# Is there any way to know what properties/variables are available in html template in angular?

Tags: angular, jsonforms

Is there any way to know what properties/variables are available in html template in angular?
I tried    {{ this | json }} appears error.

I use json forms (https://jsonforms.io/) and I have this template for my custom renderer

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 xyz">
    <span class="text-info text-open">{{ description }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 zyx">
    <span class="text-open-content">{{ data }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just by chance typed these vars **description** and **data**, and it gave me values of them, but there is no documentation for these properties and I just don't understand from where goes these values.
I need a way to know what vars/properties are available for my template.

And in my ts file there are no such vars as description  and data

Comment: If you use VS Code, you can install the [Angular language service extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template)

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu, thank you, works for my needs. You can answer it so I can mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use VS Code, there's [Angular language service extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) which is a good one to have when developing Angular applications.